# Force one namespace to override / take priority over another without changing load order?

Tags: r, r-package

`select()` belongs to both the `dplyr` and `MASS` namespaces.

Ambiguity about what is called with `select()` can be solved by either

1. Loading `dplyr` *after* loading `MASS`
2. Using `dplyr::select` rather than simply `select`

Is there any other solution, preferably one that involves nominating a library to take priority over others?

Extra note: I know in the world of CSS, there's an `!important` attribute that can be added to a style so that it overrides others. I wonder if something similar exists in R which can be called when `library(dplyr)`.

Comment: Because of how `search()` works, not really, short of unloading and reloading a namespace.

Comment: I don't think so. But what is wrong with the `package::function()` method?

Comment: @prosoitos nothing wrong with `package::function()`. In my case I added a small bit of code to a large existing bit of software. The new code worked, but it broke existing code in an unexpected way (all `select`s now invoked `MASS::select`). The existing code could have been more robust if `dplyr` was somehow 'locked down' as the preferred package, preventing the issue entirely. I also take your point that functions could be called with their namespace prepended though

Comment: Right. I can see how things would be more robust if you could define this (since some functions will use other functions and you can't always prepend the package there)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether it completely solves your problem, but one option could be to use `conflict_prefer()` from `conflicted` library. From the documentation:

> conflict_prefer() allows you to declare "winners" of conflicts. You
>   can either declare a specific pairing (i.e. dplyr::filter() beats
>   base::filter()), or an overall winner (i.e. dplyr::filter() beats all
>   comers).

Let's say you want to use `between()` from `data.table`:

```
conflict_prefer("between", winner = "data.table", quiet = FALSE)

[conflicted] Removing existing preference
[conflicted] Will prefer data.table::between over any other package
```

Comment: Sounds like it does what I'm after. Do you know if something similar exists in base R?

Comment: I suppose that it does not, otherwise this library would be meaningless :) But there is a lot of hidden gems in `base R`, somebody will maybe come up with something.